# Spring Boot Application add external library component scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app, which has a library as a dependency. In this library I have several `@Component` and `@Configuration` classes, which are not scanned by Spring Boot app. I would like to add them to component scan, but I am not able to

How can this be achieved correctly? I think adding `@ComponentScan` to `MainApp` class, annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` will override the default config

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @SpringBootApplication Annotation is the combination for @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan

We can also use basePackages for scan based on requirement.

> For example common package is com.example so directory will be com -> example and sub packages. So for the project there will be different packages for the different modules like controller, service, dto, repository etc...

If we want to use any package for the component scan then we can use like below script.

Hierarchy will be :

```
com.example.controller
com.example.service
com.example.repository
```

So basePackages will be look like this :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
```

Because com.example is only the path/package which is common for all other packages. So we can use like this.

Comment: it would be better if you provided some more context, or at least an example

Comment: in my concrete context, it is about putting the component annotation on the main method of the spring app. It doesn't override the default values. For me the problem is that I provided "com.example.something" which didn't work, but just "com.example" did it's job

Comment: @AndrewT It will work when we give common path for the package, so it will be useful when we give common path for scanning. Then scan the packages will be more easy for the compiler.